# How to create a .Jar file out of a project? Gradle and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, jar, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a tool that runs analysis on compiled .Jar files with all android classes.
I have experimented a lot with gradle but I don't seem to be able to get all classes and I only get the manifest file in my .jar. Here is the gradle code:

```
task jar(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'assembleRelease') {
    from fileTree(dir: 'app/')
}
```

Below is my file directory structure 
[image]
and project details. 
[image]
Here is a sample jar that I want to generate.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to create a "fat jar" aka a jar that includes your dependencies. Check the tutorial here: https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, though the above tutorial has some java issues, on searching I found about gradle plugin shadow https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow